# GoogleAppsScript | setPictureFill doesn't work in Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my code. I'm trying to set a background by URL in GoogleSlides, but when I run the code, Google returns **TypeError: The setPictureFill function can not be found in the Page object.**

```js
var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection().getCurrentPage();
var img = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/9bTjZrytydVRK/giphy.gif';
slide.setPictureFill(img);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `slide` is page object, but `page` objects do not have a `setPictureFill()` method;hence the error. What you need is a `PageBackground` object. Try the following:

```
function my_fill() {
   var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection().getCurrentPage();
   var page_background = slide.getBackground();
   var img = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/9bTjZrytydVRK/giphy.gif';
   page_background.setPictureFill(img);
}
```

Which successfully pulls the animated space GIF as the background.